# jQuery wrapAll() is not working with ul class

Tags: jquery, wrapall

I have a small script code with a `wrapAll()` function that works with a div id when I target the div ID but if I try to target a ul class, it is not working:

```
<script>
        $("#block-tb-megamenu-main-menu").wrapAll("<div class='tb-megamenu tb-megamenu-main-menu style-white'/>");
      </script>

<section id="block-tb-megamenu-main-menu" class="block block-tb-megamenu clearfix">

<ul class="tb-megamenu-nav nav level-0 items-4">
  <li data-id="398" data-level="1" data-type="menu_item" data-class="" data-xicon="" data-caption="" data-alignsub="" data-group="0" data-hidewcol="0" data-hidesub="0" class="tb-megamenu-item level-1 mega dropdown">
  <a href="/solutions" class="dropdown-toggle disabled">

    Solutions         
          </a>
</li>
</ul>
</section>
```

If I change the `#block-tb-megamenu-main-menu` to `ul.tb-megamenu-nav` (or `just .tb-megamenu-nav`) the script does not work. I was wondering if anyone had any insight on why it does not work.

Comment: works fine if you add a doc ready handler

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3cURA/2/

Comment: If that's truly the order you have things in your page, then `#block-tb-megamenu-main-menu` is not in the DOM yet when your script runs.  Move the script AFTER the content or use jQuery's `.ready()` capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the script in a dom ready handler and see

```
jQuery(function(){
    $("ul.tb-megamenu-nav").wrapAll("<div class='tb-megamenu tb-megamenu-main-menu style-white'/>");
})
```

Demo: [Wrap UL](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3cURA/), [Wrap Section](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3cURA/4/)